# Changing widths of element according to number of elements in parent element

Tags: html, css, row, col

I am writing a HTML page consists of rows and columns in DIV elements.

Sometimes a row may only contain 1 column, some 2, and some 3, and I want to change the width of each column depending on how many columns there are in a row.

Here is my HTML examples here:

```
<!-- 1 column -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 100% -->
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>

<!-- 2 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 75% -->
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>

<!-- 3 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 50% -->
  <div class="col"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

I am unsure how I would code this in CSS however and was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to to add another class to the `row` divs, designating how many divs it contains:

```
<!-- 3 columns -->
<div class="row col3">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 50% -->
  <div class="col"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

and add styles accordingly:

```
.col3 div {
   width: 33%;
}
```

This would give all `div`-elements in a div with class `col3` 33% width.

Comment: I understand that, however the number of columns is going to be dynamic throughout the application, which will mean more PHP code . I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I forgot I will have a PHP variable which will determine how many columns are in that row. I will accept this answer as it is the most efficient way! Thanks

Comment: I see. Thank you :) Just a note: adding the CSS class via PHP is the best solution, everything else would mean complicated CSS or JS hacks.

Comment: The variable will read column-2, column-3 or just column, so I can pass that variable into the HTML document! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set up grid classes with different widths (`100%`, `75%`, `50%`, etc) depending on the size you want and add that to the `div`:

**HTML**

```
<!-- 2 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col quarter"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 75% -->
  <div class="col three-quarters"></div>
</div>

<!-- 3 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col quarter"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 50% -->
  <div class="col half"></div>

  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col quarter"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col{
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
}

.full{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.three-quarters{
    width: 75%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

.half{
    width: 50%;
    background: black;
    float: left;
}

.quarter{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/36L6w8bp/)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS set up classes for the different sizes you want. For example `col-1` will be 25%,
`col-2` 50%, etc...

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 100% -->
  <div class="col-4">100%</div>
</div>

<!-- 2 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col-1">25%</div>

  <!-- Column will be 75% -->
  <div class="col-3">75%</div>
</div>

<!-- 3 columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col-1">25%</div>

  <!-- Column will be 50% -->
  <div class="col-2">50%</div>

  <!-- Column will be 25% -->
  <div class="col-1">25%</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
    background-color:#ccc;
    float: left;
}
.row {
    clear:left;
}
.col-1 {
    width:25%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/otpozn20/)